# Ionic $cordovaDialogs Beep

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I need for my Ionic Reminder App some kind of audio notification and I think the CordovaDialogs Beep  function could do the trick.

The only problem is when I try to execute it I got the famous error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'beep' of undefined

It's crazy because the alert, prompt and confirm functions work flawlessly on my browser ... and yes I did update the ngCordova to last version so I can play with it on my browser.

The code I try to run is as simple as that :

```
.controller('statusCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaDialogs) {

  $cordovaDialogs.beep(3);

})
```

If I try to console the $cordovaDialogs Object in the controller I can clearly see the beep function.

Thanks.

Comment: No one used beep function yet ? Weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually added some things in the controller ($ionicPlatform etc) and managed to make working on the device. On browser vibrate and beep doesn't work and I am ok with that except the console errors.

```
.controller('statusCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDevice, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaVibration,$cordovaDialogs) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {

          // getting device infor from $cordovaDevice
          var device = $cordovaDevice.getDevice();

          $scope.manufacturer = device.manufacturer;
          $scope.model = device.model;
          $scope.platform = device.platform;
          $scope.uuid = device.uuid;
          $cordovaVibration.vibrate(100);
          $cordovaDialogs.beep(3);

        });

    });

})
```